# Canvas to Bitmap in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a problem I want to convert a Canvas object to Bitmap then perform an operation on a bitmap and then convert this new Bitmap to the Canvas in OnDraw method, this is my code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas to Bitmap
    Bitmap newBitmap = fastblur(bitmap,10);
    c = newBitmap to Canvas
    m_view.vDraw(c);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to make a back buffer?

```
Bitmap backbuffer;
Canvas backbufferCanvas;

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    if(backbuffer != null){
        backbuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), new Bitmap.Config());
        backbufferCanvas = new Canvas(backbuffer);
    }
    //Draw to backbufferCanvas
    canvas.draw(backbuffer, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I want:1. Convert canvas to Bitmap, 2. Do something on Bitmap , 3. Convert new Bitmap to Canvas.

Comment: And that makes no sense.  You don't convert canvases and bitmaps into each other.  If you mean you want to draw on a canvas and have it go to a bitmap, then draw that bitmap to the screen what I did is right.

Comment: Yes beacuse I have function to to blur image and that function need bitmap: public Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) { }

Comment: So, did you get the solution ?